# Is it OK to name a function parameter window in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, testing

Is it OK to name a function parameter `window` in JavaScript (if said parameter will correspond to the window object at runtime)?

In short I want to inject the window object into the function to improve testability, but I am aware this will hide direct access to the window object within the function with said parameter.

Comment: I was going to say the same thing as @adeneo, but I was going to add that causing possible confusion like this is not a good idea. You do not have to call it `window`, do you?

Comment: This is *variable shadowing*, you are using the symbol in a new scope, its unrelated to its original context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window` is not a [reserved keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words), so you could name the parameter `window` if you wanted to.

Using a variable/argument is common in IIFE's to help with minimizing and keeping the value of `window` constant, you will often see things like

```
(function(window, undefined) {

   // code

})(window);
```

and there are really no issues with this, other than maybe confusion if you decide to use something like

```
function stuff(window) {
    window.value = 'woot';
}

stuff( document.querySelector('input') ); // confusing ?
```

which is confusing.